# Why is param in this lambda expression?

Tags: mvvm, relaycommand, lambda

The [MSDN magazine article by Josh Smith on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) contains a lambda expression I don't completely understand. What is the purpose of **param** in this code?

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Save(),
                param => this.CanSave );
```

Translated to my preferred language VB it's:

```
Dim saveAction as New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf Me.Save)
_saveCommand = New RelayCommand(saveAction, Function(param) Me.CanSave)
```

I would have expected to only see **param** if it is used within CanSave or Save. I am somewhat new to lambda expressions. It's odd for me to see a variable that is neither declared nor used anywhere as far as I can tell. Any explanation would be appreciated.

To put this in context the constructor for RelayCommand (C#) is:

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
```

and in VB:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Action(Of Object), _
               ByVal canExecute As Predicate(Of Object))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda expression *is* declaring it - the place where it appears is basically a declaration. If it didn't, it wouldn't be compatible with `Action(Of Object)`. That's why it's there - even though you don't actually need the value.

With anonymous methods, if you don't need any parameter values you can omit the parameter list entirely:

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(delegate { this.Save(); },
     delegate { return this.CanSave; });
```

... but you can't do that with lambda expressions. You *have* to specify the parameter list - either just as a parameter name for a single parameter, or a full list in brackets. The code you've presented is equivalent to:

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommand((Object param) => this.Save(),
     (Object param) => this.CanSave);
```

Comment: I think I get it now. But why is execute declared as Action(Of Object) when Object is ignored? Is it because RelayCommand Implements ICommand.Execute (which takes an object parameter)? Confusing stuff - I miss VB6!

Comment: @DeveloperDan: `RelayCommand` itself doesn't know whether or not you're going to ignore the parameter. It will *give* you the relevant value - it just so happens that these delegates are going to ignore it. Think of it as being like an event handler - not every event handler bothers using `sender` or `args`, do they? They just merrily ignore them, and all is well. It's exactly the same here.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You've explained this well. And I see you're quite prolific. I intend to learn a lot more from your other posts, webcasts & podcasts.

Comment: @DeveloperDan: Glad it helped - and yes, I do tend to spew my thoughts fairly widely on the net :)

Comment: I found a helpful post at: http://community.visual-basic.it/alessandroenglish/archive/2010/06/25/29800.aspx It says "...notice that the param argument in methods is never used but it is required by the interface's signatures."